# Floating Action Button and CardView

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview, android-cardview, floating-action-button

How to add Floating Action Button from the support library for `CardView` so that when you scroll through the `ScrollView`, the button has gone up along with the card?

### My app

before scrolling

[image: before scrolling]

after scrolling

[image: after scrolling]

The button should go along with the card

I want to fix this

### Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white_vk_background_color">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_8"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_16">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:id="@+id/behavior_card_view"
                style="@style/RateCardView"

                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_2"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_8">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_16"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_8">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/description_rate_usd_text_view"
                            style="@style/AppTextView.RateTextView"
                            android:text="@string/description_currency_text_view_usd"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rate_usd_text_view"
                            style="@style/AppTextView.RateTextView"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description_rate_usd_text_view"
                            tools:text="63.99"
                            />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rate_difference_usd_text_view"
                            style="@style/AppTextView.DifferenceTextView"

                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rate_usd_text_view"
                            tools:text="+0.44"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_8">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/description_rate_eur_text_view"
                            style="@style/AppTextView.RateTextView"
                            android:text="@string/description_currency_text_view_eur"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rate_eur_text_view"
                            style="@style/AppTextView.RateTextView"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description_rate_eur_text_view"
                            tools:text="71.99"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rate_difference_eur_text_view"
                            style="@style/AppTextView.DifferenceTextView"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rate_eur_text_view"
                            tools:text="+0.15"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/rate_update_time_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_8"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_16"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_16"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_date"


                        tools:text="Date: 15.07.2016"

                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/converter_card_view"
                style="@style/RateCardView"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_2"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_8">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_16">

                    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

                        android:id="@+id/converter_ruble_edit_text"
                        style="@style/RateEditText"
                        android:hint="@string/description_currency_ruble"

                        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
                        app:met_bottomTextSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_converter"
                        app:met_errorColor="@color/red_light"
                        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
                        app:met_floatingLabelAlwaysShown="true"
                        app:met_floatingLabelTextSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_converter"
                        app:met_helperText=""
                        app:met_primaryColor="@color/red_light"
                        app:met_textColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

                    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

                        android:id="@+id/converter_dollar_edit_text"
                        style="@style/RateEditText"
                        android:hint="@string/description_currency_dollar"

                        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
                        app:met_bottomTextSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_converter"
                        app:met_errorColor="@color/red_light"
                        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
                        app:met_floatingLabelAlwaysShown="true"
                        app:met_floatingLabelTextSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_converter"
                        app:met_helperText=""
                        app:met_primaryColor="@color/red_light"
                        app:met_textColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>


                    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText

                        android:id="@+id/converter_euro_edit_text"
                        style="@style/RateEditText"
                        android:hint="@string/description_currency_euro"

                        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
                        app:met_bottomTextSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_converter"
                        app:met_errorColor="@color/red_light"
                        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
                        app:met_floatingLabelAlwaysShown="true"
                        app:met_floatingLabelTextSize="@dimen/density_font_size_text_converter"
                        app:met_helperText=""

                        app:met_primaryColor="@color/red_light"

                        app:met_textColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/update_floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/density_spacing_size_floating_action_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/float_action_button_spacing_8"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cached_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/behavior_card_view"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="end|right|center"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You want to achieve something like this: https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsQUxBamxwdy15Vlk/patterns_actions_fab1.png ?

Comment: I Added screenshots of my problem

Comment: Ok, but please also post your layout (and code if relevant).

Comment: Use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView and add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to it. Hope this will help u

Comment: That not work, the screen does not scroll

Answer (score 0):

Instead of anchoring to behavior_card_view, try anchoring it to something inside behavior_card_view. Ideally, anchor to the bottom of the USD textview. This should prevent the FAB from sliding down.

I would actually create a invisible layout which I can use to anchor but it doesn't affect the UI otherwise.

I can't replicate the issue you are having but the following works as you want:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rl1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp" 
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv1" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:paddingLeft="12dp" 
            android:text="Setting" 
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
            android:id="@+id/fab" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add" 
            app:fabSize="mini" 
            app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp" 
            app:layout_anchorGravity="end|right|center" 
            app:layout_anchor="@id/tv1" />
... a lot of elements here ...
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This RelativeLayout is the only element inside my ScrollView element.

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help me help you! You have to be more descriptive than that.

I suspect the problem is that the FAB is sliding down because the height of the anchor is >>> height of the FAB. So, the solution I proposed is to prevent the FAB from sliding down by restricting the height of the anchor element.

Comment: Ok,sorry, I created FrameLayout inside the card and attached to it a button,but when I scroll button does not go under the status bar

Comment: I put the card inside the frame and scrolling was successful, but now the problem to put the button over the edge of the card, as in the case of anchor

Comment: I can't replicate your issue but I added code that works as you want for me. I also rearranged the XML for FAB directly under its anchor.